# How to load a SVG-File from QRC

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a vectorlayer and want to give the points a svg-symbol. If I give the constructor an absolute path to my svg-file it works fine. Then i put the svg to my ressource file (qrc) and try to load it from there it doesn't work. Maybe I'll have to load the file into a QIcon? But how can I get it then in the layer? I've read something about QSvgCache but I see no way to use it. Can anyone help me?

```
            //QString name="E:\\Entwicklung\\QGis\\Quantum-GiS\\src\\plugins\\adresssuche\\haus.svg";
            QFile svg(":/adresssucheplugin/haus.svg");
            QString name=svg.fileName()
            qDebug()<<name;
            QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2* p_svgSymbolLayer(0);
            p_svgSymbolLayer= new QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2(svg.fileName(), DEFAULT_SVGMARKER_SIZE, DEFAULT_SVGMARKER_ANGLE);
```

Comment: Did you also try to use it like this: `QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2( "qrc:///adresssucheplugin/haus.svg", ... )`

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Thanks for the hope, but it doesn't solved the problem, I also tried "svg:/..." :-(

Comment: I followed the constructor in code of QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer2 and found out it is not possible to load an svg in that way. Maybe it is possible in python but in c++ it is not. So I had to solve my problem otherway. Is not so bad but maybe its a wish for the future...